# Core Data how to change NSNumber to NSString?

Tags: iphone, core-data

I am using Core Data for my app and I have a model Reservation and there I have a facebook_event_id which at first I had as a Integer 64 but the problem is that this is perhaps to short and I would like it to change to NSString (I get it as JSON string from Facebook anyway).

I have done the following for now:

- Editor -> Add model version and based it on my older one
- rebuild my subclasses
- added this dict with NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption and NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption set to YES

When I tested it to change between Integer 16 and 64 everything worked fine but when I try to  change from Integer 64 and String it gives me an error:

`Can't find or automatically infer mapping model for migration`

So I added a new mapping model and there I wanted to fix it in `ReservationRoReservation | facebook_event_id | $source.facebook_event_id`

I think one should do something with `$source.facebook_event_id` to get it converted but I have no idea what to write in the to get it to work. One should not use plain Objective-C there but a [NSExpression](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSExpression_Class/Reference/NSExpression.html), but nowhere there it explains how to convert a NSNumber to a NSString.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want:

```
FUNCTION($source.facebook_event_id, "stringValue")
```

Which will take the NSNumber currently in your facebook_event_id property, and send the stringValue message to it.

Comment: Does apple has documents about these migration policies like that? Can you provide me where can I read to use that kind of FUNCTION($source.X, "functionName")?

Comment: @Eddie I don't think they have very good documentation, but these might get you started: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmMappingOverview.html and http://stackoverflow.com/a/14068104/1196205

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
NSString *convertedString = [NSNumber stringValue];
```

Comment: I don't have any code, the $source.facebook_event_id is an NSEspression in a migration model one creates in Xcode (it has the .xmappingmodel file extention), one can not use Obj-C code there. It looks something like that: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Art/recipes1-2mapping.jpg