# iOS: what is the value expression function when migrating coredata relationship?

Tags: ios, core-data, core-data-migration

The function for a relationship is like: `FUNCTION($manager, "destinationInstancesForEntityMappingNamed:sourceInstances:","employeesToEmployees",$source.employees")`

What is this "Function"? How will it be called? Is there any guide introducing to this?

I've read Apple's

*[Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html)*

but I still don't get this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a "function expressions with arbitrary method invocations" which seem to be very poorly documented. The only reference that I know of is one paragraph in the [NSExpression Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsexpression?language=objc):

> **Function Expressions**
>
> On OS X v10.4, `NSExpression` only supports a
>   predefined set of functions: `sum`, `count`, `min`, `max`, and `average`. These
>   predefined functions were accessed in the predicate syntax using
>   custom keywords (for example, `MAX(1, 5, 10)`).
>
> On OS X v10.5 and later, function expressions also support arbitrary
>   method invocations. To use this extended functionality, you can now
>   use the syntax `FUNCTION(receiver, selectorName, arguments, ...)`, for
>   example:
>
> `FUNCTION(@"/Developer/Tools/otest", @"lastPathComponent") => @"otest"`

The quoting in that sample code seems be incorrect. But the following code compiles and runs on iOS 5/6:

```
NSExpression *expr = [NSExpression expressionWithFormat:@"FUNCTION('/Developer/Tools/otest', 'lastPathComponent')"];
id result = [expr expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil];
NSLog(@"result: %@", result);
// Output:
// otest
```

So in your case, it is a function expression which calls, when evaluated

```
[$manager destinationInstancesForEntityMappingNamed:@"employeesToEmployees"
                                    sourceInstances:$source.employees]
```

where `$manager` and `$source` are replaced by the migration manager and the source object, as described in [Mapping Model Objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmMappingOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004399-CH5-SW2) in the "Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration Programming Guide".