# Adding relations during a Core Data migration – self reference

Tags: ios, core-data, nsexpression

I am performing a core data migration using a [mapping model](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13945704/2547229).

The new model adds a relationship on the `Report` entity called `rootReport`.

**I'd like to make this relation mandatory**, rather than optional. For **existing** `Report` entities, `rootReport` should be a self reference.  Reports that will be added in the future will reference other reports as their root, not just themselves.

The link I gave has a good overview of how the expressions in the mapping model work – they're the same things that are compatible with [NSExpression](http://nshipster.com/nsexpression/). Based on this, I'm using the following mapping rule for rootReport:

```
FUNCTION($manager,
         "destinationInstancesForEntityMappingNamed:sourceInstances:",
         "ReportToReport", 
         $source.SELF)
```

[I formatted that – in the file it's all squashed up on one line.]

However, I've not managed to get this to work for my rootReport relation. I always get a validation error following migration with the complaint that rootReport is not set for some report:

> NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134110 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (Cocoa error 134110.)\" UserInfo=0x7b294630 {attribute=rootReport, entity=Report, reason=Validation error missing attribute values on mandatory destination relationship}"

Any clues on what's going wrong, or suggestions on how to debug? The processing is all in App Kit, so by the time the exception shows up I don't have any context to poke and investigate!

---

There is a good walk through of the hierarchy of mappings, from completely automatic to fully manual, and all the steps between [here](http://9elements.com/io/index.php/customizing-core-data-migrations/).

If you want to know more about what you can do with these mapping expressions (which *does* work well for attributes, at least), there're good articles [here](http://funwithobjc.tumblr.com/post/2922267976/using-custom-functions-with-nsexpression) and [here](http://nshipster.com/nsexpression/).

It's easy to set up mapping expressions to call arbitrary code from your project, or existing methods on the data. It's all pretty clean and elegant.

You do this using the `FUNCTION` expression, which the default relation mappings call. To call class methods you use `FUNCTION(CAST("<Class-Name>", "Class"), "<class-method-name>", <any>, <arguments>, <in>, <a>, <list>)` as shown [here](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/197476-custom-entity-migration-policies-atribute-from-nsstring-to-nsdate.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what was going wrong above.

It's possible that I had made changes to the destination data model *after* I created the mapping model, which I didn't imagine would be a problem. However, looking at mapping models with a text editor, they contain large binary blobs which I suspect might represent the source and target data models at the time of creation.

I removed and recreated the mapping model and now I'm having no problem with self references of the form:

```
FUNCTION($manager,
        "destinationInstancesForEntityMappingNamed:sourceInstances:",
        "ReportToReport", 
        $source)
```

This is nearly identical to the expression used in the question, which I found didn't work. Note, this working expression uses simply `$source` instead of `$source.SELF`. However, I'm pretty sure I would have tried that before, so I don't know if this is the only thing I was getting wrong.